# Как установить программу make на windows 8.1

Tags: windows, makefile

Работаю на windows 8.1 64bit, использую phpstorm.
Изучая один мануал, для примера создал Makefile со следующим содержимым:

```
cli:
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/5_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app php:7.2-cli php bin/app.php
```

после чего, запустил в терминале phpstorm-а команду `make cli` и конечно получил ошибку. Погуглил, нашел плагин для phpstorm Makefile support https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9333-makefile-support/ - установил его, перезагрузил IDE, после чего снова получил ошибку:

```
make cli
"make" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Понимаю, что нужно установить софт из "мира" linux. Подскажите что ещё нужно доустановить чтобы эта команда заработала на моём phpstorm под windows 8.1 64bit.
Нагуглил прогу gnuwin32, но пишут что она только для windows 32bit. Подскажите, что нужно установить конкретно в моём случае и чтобы make работал глобально (т.е. был доступен отовсюду в системе)

Comment: Вы понимаете, что этот мейкфайл просто запускает одну команду и все? Можно было бы с тем же успехом скопипастить эту команду в терминал...

Comment: Если все-таки хотите `make`, посмотрите в сторону [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: установил MSYS2. После чего установил make командой "pacman -S make".
Далее, при переходе в папку с Makefile и попыткой запустить make cli получаю ошибку
Makefile:2: *** несколько образцов цели.  Останов.
В консоли phpstorm-а команда по-прежнему не работает. Подскажите как заставить работать команду make?

Вот скрин с ошибкой: https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2019/10/17543a171497bce62bc57435db5877ac.jpg

Comment: перед `docker` табуляция стоит? с пробелами make  не будет работать